# Collapsible list with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement [this code](http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/collapsible-lists/) into my website. Basically,

1. I downloaded the .js file, added to the main folder, and added the following to the head of the HTML file:
2. Added a trivial list to the HTML file:

   ```
   <ul class="collapsibleList">
   <li>
   Test 1
   <ul>
   <li>Yes</li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
   Test 2
   <ul>
   <li>No</li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   </ul>
   ```
3. and added some styling to the CSS, to have a plus/minus icon when the tree is closed/open:

   ```
   .collapsibleList li{
   list-style-image: url(images/plus.svg);
   cursor: auto;
   }

   li.collapsibleListOpen{
   list-style-image: url(images/minus.svg);
   cursor: pointer;
   }

   li.collapsibleListClosed{
   list-style-image: url(images/plus.svg);
   cursor: pointer;
   }
   ```

Yet, the code does not work. This seems to be because I need to "apply" the function to the given element. As the page states:

> The apply function turns any list with the class ‘collapsibleList’ into a tree view and collapses its sub-lists:

```
1 // make the appropriate lists collapsible
2 CollapsibleLists.apply();
```

> This function should generally be called immediately after page load, using code such as runOnLoad.

But then I got lost. I checked the [referred page](http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/running-tasks-on-load/), added the RunOnLoad js to the page too, but still nothing.

This must be a trivial issue. As you could guess, I know next to nothing of JS. I just want to add a nice collapsible tree, which has different symbols when open and closed. JS seems to be the only choice here.

**UPDATE**: I went to the source code of the page I am getting the code from, because the author shows one example of a collapsible list. Then, I implemented his code into mine. In particular, I added the following into my head:

```
<script>var runOnLoad=function(c,o,d,e){function x(){for(e=1;c.length;)c.shift()()}o[d]?(document[d]('DOMContentLoaded',x,0),o[d]('load',x,0)):o.attachEvent('onload',x);return function(t){e?o.setTimeout(t,0):c.push(t)}}([],window,'addEventListener');</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

This was the bit that I thought I was missing. Yet, I can't make it work! 
      runOnLoad(function(){ CollapsibleLists.apply(); });

```
</script>
```

Comment: I haven't seen this site added the script tags with the source codes in their html code.... interesting...try <script src="absolute_path_to.js"></script> for each script

Comment: @repzero doesn't make a difference. See updated post though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    //your code to run since DOM is loaded and ready
    CollapsibleLists.apply();
});
```

if you're using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 CollapsibleLists.apply();
})
```

Comment: It did not work. I actually copied part of the source code that the author had in his own website, because he shows a collapsible list there. See updated question. Still doesn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should use the code...

```
<script src="CollapsibleLists.js"></script>

<script>var runOnLoad=function(c,o,d,e){function x(){for(e=1;c.length;)c.shift()()}o[d]?(document[d]('DOMContentLoaded',x,0),o[d]('load',x,0)):o.attachEvent('onload',x);return function(t){e?o.setTimeout(t,0):c.push(t)}}([],window,'addEventListener');</script>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
      runOnLoad(function(){ CollapsibleLists.apply(); });
</script>
```